# Vlookup using multiple conditions [Vlookup & Hlookup combined]

Tags: google-sheets

I want to populate my review sheet using the raw data sheet.

Daily data is appended in the raw data sheet. I think a combination of vlookup & hlookup is requried but not sure how to procees on this.

Review sheet
[image]

Raw sales sheet
[image]

[Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PopEhC4ObXtYbZaxC9RMwEzRg9gRrOoeM4EvLjaeVRw/edit#gid=0) to the sample sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below formula in`'B2` of the `Review` sheet:-

```
=SUMIFS(Raw!$C:$C,Raw!$A:$A,Review!B$1,Raw!$B:$B,Review!$A2)
```

Then either drag the formula or do a copy-paste to other cells.

Hope that works.

Comment: Thanks, works! Is there a way this can be done via index match as well?